# Inverse Fourier transform of two variable function $F(k_x,k_y)=e^{ikz} e^{-ik_\rho ^2 z /2k}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, exponential-function

I am trying to find the inverse [Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) of:
$$ F(k_x,k_y)=e^{ikz} e^{-ik_\rho ^2 z /2k}, $$ 
where $k^2 = k_x^2 +k_y^2 +k_z^2 = k_\rho ^2 +k_z^2 $ is a constant.

I am getting confused as to how to go about this. 
Inverse fourier transform of $F(k_x)$ would be given by
$ \int F(k_x)e^{-ik_x x} \frac{dk_x}{2\pi} $?
How do I change this when there is a function of two variables?

Furthermore, could anyone explain what is meant by the prefactor of the exponential?

Comment: [This thesis chapter](http://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsoftaee261/chap8.pdf) has a nice discussion on higher dimensional Fourier transforms.

Comment: Is the $z$ in the exponential just a constant?

Comment: I guess so but i'm not sure... the question doesn't state